# Creating spatial layer from MS SQL Server table?

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, shapely, fiona

I have a table in MSSQL that I am trying to use to create a spatial layer from using the QgsVectorLayer function to load the table as a layer, and then using Fiona to create a shapefile but I am having problems in working out whether I am going about this in the correct way!

My code is below - I am able to connect to my MSSQL table so have it loaded as a QgsVectorLayer, but I am struggling with instructing Fiona / Shapely to convert the table to a spatial layer by using the XREF and YREF fields from my table as the geometry.

Looking at my code, am I along the right lines here? It does not produce any file so I obviously need to adapt this!

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant 

from osgeo import ogr
import os

from shapely import wkb, geometry
import fiona
import ogrtools

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Pisa\\apps\\qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
print 'QGIS Application initialized'

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Pisa\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing
print 'QGIS processing framework initialized'

driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(driverName)
GazProp_shp = "X:\\llpg_test.shp"
GGP_LLPG_shp = "X:\\GGP_LLPG.shp"
GGP_LLPG_test = "X:\\ggp_llpg_test.shp"

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection("myserver", "", "GGPNLPGRDC", "GGPAccessRDC", "GGPAccessRDC")
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally
# subset (WHERE clause)
uri.setDataSource("dbo", "ADDRESSTABLE","")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "ADDRESSTABLE", "mssql")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "llpg_tan layer loaded successfully"

with fiona.open(vlayer, 'r') as input:
    input.schema['geometry'] = "Point"
    with fiona.open(GGP_LLPG_test, 'w', driverName, input.schema.copy(), 'EPSG:27700') as output:
        for elem in input:
            #geometry
            points=Point(input['XREF'], input['YREF'])
            output.write({'properties': elem['properties'],'geometry': mapping(points)})
        print 'Job done!'
```